# Git push sync throws remote: error: refusing to delete the current default branch 'refs/heads/master'

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-mirror, git-sync

I am trying to sync my github repo with AWS codecommit. while trying to do `git push sync --mirror`, I am not sure why it's trying to delete. Same code works fine for the `master` branch, when I shift to `preprod` branch it fails with the below error

```
remote: error: refusing to delete the current default branch 'refs/heads/master'.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test-repo'
```

**Commands I am executing in my pipeline.**

```
git config --global credential.'https://git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com'.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
git remote add sync https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test-repo
git push sync --mirror
```

Comment: Could it be that you have `main` instead of `master`?

Comment: @matt this is an old repo and we still use `master`. same steps work fine from `master` branch, when I checkout to `preprod` branch it fails with the above error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered by [the `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), although you need to know what you're looking at:

> `--mirror`
>        Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
> `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`,
> `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote
> repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote
> end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
> and **deleted refs will be removed from the remote end**.

(emphasis mine)

Git, of course, has no idea what refs were "deleted": it just assumes that if *you* don't have some ref, such as `refs/heads/master`, in *your* repository, it should tell the other repository to delete *its* ref.  So:

> ```
> remote: error: refusing to delete the current default branch 'refs/heads/master'.
> ```

This clearly means that your repository does not have a `refs/heads/master`, and your `git push --mirror` is therefore asking them (whoever they are) to delete *theirs* too.  But they're programmed to refuse to delete whatever branch name is set as the *default branch*.

Remember that the default branch is the name they, whoever they are, will recommend that `git clone` *check out* at the end of the cloning process, should the person running `git clone` fail to supply a `-b` option.  Most web hosting sites offer a way to set this name.  Since you mention GitHub, consider using `gh` or their web API to set the default branch to something other than `master` to avoid the error.  **However...**

You mention [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055717/git-push-sync-throws-remote-error-refusing-to-delete-the-current-default-branc/73059274#comment129031133_73055717) that:

> this is an old repo and we still use `master`. same steps work fine from `master` branch, when I checkout to `preprod` branch it fails with the above error ...

This strongly suggests that the repository from which you are running `git push` has *only one branch name*.  As such, your `git push --mirror` will *delete all other branch names*.  If that's what you want, you're on the right track.  If not, reconsider the use of `--mirror` in the first place.